# How to groupby a dataframe based on one column and transpose based on another column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, transpose

I have a dataframe with values as:

| col_1 | Timestamp | data_1 | data_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | 22/12/2001 | 0.21 | 0.2 |
| abb | 22/12/2001 | 0.20 | 0 |
| acc | 22/12/2001 | 0.12 | 0.19 |
| aaa | 23/12/2001 | 0.23 | 0.21 |
| abb | 23/12/2001 | 0.32 | 0.18 |
| acc | 23/12/2001 | 0.52 | 0.20 |

I need to group the dataframe based on the **timestamp** and add columns w.r.t the **col_1** column for **data_1** and **data_2** such as:

| Timestamp | aaa_data_1 | abb_data_1 | acc_data_1 | aaa_data_2 | abb_data_2 | acc_data_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22/12/2001 | 0.21 | 0.20 | 0.12 | 0.2 | 0 | 0.19 |
| 23/12/2001 | 0.23 | 0.32 | 0.52 | 0.21 | 0.18 | 0.20 |

I am able to group by based on timestamp but not finding a way to update/add the columns.

And with  `df.pivot(index='Timestamp', columns='col_1')`, I get

| Timestamp | aaa_data_1 | abb_data_1 | acc_data_1 | aaa_data_2 | abb_data_2 | acc_data_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22/12/2001 |  |  | 0.12 |  |  | 0.19 |
| 22/12/2001 |  | 0.20 |  |  | 0 |  |
| 22/12/2001 | 0.21 |  |  | 0.2 |  |  |
| 23/12/2001 |  |  | 0.52 |  |  | 0.20 |
| 23/12/2001 |  | 0.32 |  |  | 0.18 |  |
| 23/12/2001 | 0.23 |  |  | 0.21 |  |  |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@CodeDifferent's answer suffices, since your data does not have aggregation; an alternative option is the dev version of `pivot_wider` from `pyjanitor` (they are wrappers around pandas functions):

```
# pip install git+https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor.git
import pandas as pd
import janitor as jn
df.pivot_wider(index='Timestamp', 
               names_from='col_1', 
               levels_order=['col_1', None],
               names_sep='_')

    Timestamp  aaa_data_1  abb_data_1  acc_data_1  aaa_data_2  abb_data_2  acc_data_2
0  22/12/2001        0.21        0.20        0.12        0.20        0.00        0.19
1  23/12/2001        0.23        0.32        0.52        0.21        0.18        0.20
```

This will fail if there are duplicates in the combination of `index` and `names_from`; in that case you can use the `pivot_table`, which takes care of duplicates:

```py
(df.pivot_table(index='Timestamp', columns='col_1')
   .swaplevel(axis = 1)
   .pipe(lambda df: df.set_axis(df.columns.map('_'.join), axis =1))
)
 
            aaa_data_1  abb_data_1  acc_data_1  aaa_data_2  abb_data_2  acc_data_2
Timestamp                                                                         
22/12/2001        0.21        0.20        0.12        0.20        0.00        0.19
23/12/2001        0.23        0.32        0.52        0.21        0.18        0.20
```

Or with a helper method from `pyjanitor`, for a bit of a *cleaner* method chaining syntax:

```py
(df.pivot_table(index='Timestamp', columns='col_1')
   .swaplevel(axis = 1)
   .collapse_levels()
```

Comment: @CodeDifferent, I tried all the three ways specified by both of you. But for all of them, I get something like the third table.

Comment: is this on the sample data shared?

Comment: could you confirm it works on the sample data?

Comment: actual data has around 300000 rows

Comment: ok, so the groupby, what is the aggregation method? mean? sum? ...

Comment: I need to group w.r.t Timestamp, and no aggregation on the data_1 or data_2

Comment: is there any way I can combine the rows in table 3 based on the Timestamp? Even that will help!

Comment: with the current output, could you try : ``df.groupby('Timestamp').sum()?`` does it change anything?

Answer (score 2):

A pivot plus a column rename are all you need:

```py
result = df.pivot(index='Timestamp', columns='col_1')
result.columns = [f'{col_1}_{data}' for data, col_1 in result.columns]
```